# Is there a way to search token history rather than entire commands

Tags: fish

The default fish or fzf implementations for ctrl-R is very helpful for looking through and replacing the prompt buffer with lines in `history`. Is there something similar to alt-up/down, `history-token-search-backward` but that lists all previous arguments rather than entire lines of commands?

Would be useful when using commands with long lists of complicated flags that are hard to remember. The exact combination of flags haven't been used in the past, but I want to search from previous usages of particular flags used in other combinations.

Comment: Not that I can think of, but isn't that more what auto-completion of arguments is for?  If I don't remember a flag, I just type `-`, then Tab to get a list of the arguments.  If I want to see how I might have used it in the past, then that would be the domain of `fzf`.